# Call Java library from Kotlin Native

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am using Kotlin Native to create code that will run on two separate operating systems (MacOS and Android).  Both machines will have JVMs installed.

I have a Java library that cannot be rewritten in Kotlin, as it relies on an open-souce third party Java dependency -- specifically [WireMock](https://github.com/wiremock) but I don't think that's relevant to answer the broader question.

Are there options for Java interop beyond invoking a standalone JAR from the Native shell/terminal?  Is there something that can be achieved via the JNI to allow for programatic invocation of the JAR from Kotlin Native?

Comment: The linked provided explains how to call Java code from kotlin-jvm.  This is well understood and documented.  It's a simpler technical problem because, in this case, the Kotlin code is running off the JVM too.

The important part of my question is that it pertains to Kotlin native specifically.

Comment: Ah sorry, I glossed over that.

Comment: JNI is for calling native code _from_ Java, not the other way around, so I can't see how it could help.  In the case of Kotlin/Native, there _is_ no JVM running, and so calling Java code will necessarily involve starting one — and I don't think Kotlin/Native has any special way of doing that (after all, it's intended to be platform-neutral!), so I suspect the only practical way is (as you say) to start it like you would any other program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can. But I would never recommend this. For MacOS and Android targets it will be better use JVM target for Kotlin instead of Kotlin/Native. Performance and developer experience will be much better this way.

If you really want to use Kotlin/Native you need first compile your java library using [Java AOT](https://openjdk.org/jeps/295) for every native target, and then use [Kotlin/Native cinterop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html).

JNI is completely opposite technology, it allows to use native libraries in JVM, not other way around.